# can we run workbench toolkit command mqsicreatebar without installation?

Tags: jenkins, automation, ibm-integration-bus

Can we build the IIB Bar file( using mqsicreatebar toolkit command) without IIB installation on jenkins box that has workspace code checked out ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to install IIB before you can use `mqsicreatebar`.

Here the important bits of a `Jenksfile` for a job that runs on Windows:

```
steps {
  script { currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' }
  bat '''
    call "C:/Program Files/IBM/IIB/10.0.0.14/server/bin/mqsiprofile.cmd" || exit /B 1
    call mqsicreatebar ...
  '''
}
```

Comment: Thank you daniel for the reply.. !!

Comment: Indeed, you need a toolkit installation, and you also need to patch it when you upgrade to new versions (this is quite important). Please also note there might be issues with the mqsicreatebar command if you run it on different OS (we had the case on IIB 10.0.0.13), the fix should be included in the next IIB release (Q2), if not already released in 10.0.0.16